# I dont know how to make this 3 column layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, multiple-columns

i have problem with this 3 column layout. I have tried something but it went wrong.
Can you help me please with this. I dont know what to do anymore. I will be so happy if you can help.There is so big gaps between adress and opening time also i dont know how to move more days and opening time to the right. Now its not clear and its messy.
Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSvH7.png

my code:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="columnn">
    <p> 
      Ruckholt Road 28</br>
      Leyton London</br>
      United Kingdom</br>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="columnn">
    <p>     
      Monday</br>
      Tuesday</br>
      Wednesday</br>
      Thursday</br>
      Friday</br>
      Saturday</br>
      Sunday</br>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="columnn">
    <p>
      11:00 - 15:30</br>
        12:00 - 18:00</br>
        Closed</br>
        12:00 - 18:00</br>
        11:00 - 14:30</br>
      Closed</br>
        Closed</br>
    </p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

```
  .columnn {
      flex: 33.33%;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    .container {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 30%;
       display: flex;
    }
```

Comment: Honestly, use a `table`,. It's tabular data after all.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your question but perhaps something like this? 
https://codepen.io/i-empty/pen/abEejeQ?editors=1100

```
   <div class="container">
  <div class="columnn">
    <p>
      Ruckholt Road 28</br>
      Leyton London</br>
      United Kingdom</br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="columnn">
    <h3> Opening Hours </h3>
    <p>
      Monday</br>
      Tuesday</br>
      Wednesday</br>
      Thursday</br>
      Friday</br>
      Saturday</br>
      Sunday</br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="columnn">
    <p>
      11:00 - 15:30</br>
      12:00 - 18:00</br>
      Closed</br>
      12:00 - 18:00</br>
      11:00 - 14:30</br>
      Closed</br>
      Closed</br>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
    .container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 30%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.columnn {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  &:last-child {
    margin: 9% 0 0 0;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was trying and i wanted something like that what i mention above in the post. You can check that, there is 3 columns. On the left is adress and on the right are days and opening hours. But there is big gap between days and opening hours. I want adress on the left and days and opening hours on the right with smaller gap between days and opening hours.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?? This is base on your code provided. Let me know

```css
.columnn {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }



.col-2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly; 
    grid-gap:20px;
   
    }

.col-1 {
    display: grid;
    }

.container {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="columnn">
    <h2> Contact Information </h2>
     <div class="col-1">
      <p> 
      Ruckholt Road 28<br>
      Leyton London<br>
      United Kingdom
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    

         
    <div>
    <h2> Hours Open </h2>
      <div class="col-2">
      <p>     
      Monday<br>
      Tuesday<br>
      Wednesday<br>
      Thursday<br>
      Friday<br>
      Saturday<br>
      Sunday
      </p>

      <p>
      11:00 - 15:30<br>
      12:00 - 18:00<br>
      Closed<br>
      12:00 - 18:00<br>
      11:00 - 14:30<br>
      Closed<br>
      Closed
      </p>
    </div>
    
 </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes its almost same like that example, but days, hours and adress are not on the same line.

Comment: @Daniel2004 Let me adjust that for you.

Comment: @Daniel2004 edited look at it.